# Use a dedicated subnet to connect all routers/firewalls?

Tags: routing, subnet, pfsense, microsoft-ftmg-2010

I have a couple router/firewall boxes (pfSense, TMG 2010, ISA 2006) on my network that are stateful. Right now they all have an interface on the same subnet as most end user devices and servers. I will be making some changes and putting some servers on their own subnets behind these firewalls so I'm wondering if I should set up one dedicated subnet for the routers to route packets to each other through. There are no routing protocols, only static routes.

I'm trying to avoid asynchronous routing which can be a problem for stateful firewalls since traffic flows in a different path into and out of the network. If traffic flows back through a different path and the firewall in that path does not have a record in the state table then the traffic could get blocked.

My basic question is this: is this an ideal way to approach this problem? Why or why not? I have not been able to find much in terms of best practices but this approach would leave only one router on each subnet so I would avoid the current situation of different machines having different default gateways.

**Current**

```
Router 1              Router 2              Router 3
192.168.1.1/24 ------ 192.168.1.2/24 ------ 192.168.1.3/24 ------ All other devices
       |                     |                      |
       V                     V                      V
10.10.10.1/24         10.20.20.1/24         10.30.30.1/24
```

**Proposed**

```
Router 1              Router 2              Router 3
192.168.1.1/24                                              ------ All other devices
10.200.200.1/24 ----- 10.200.200.2/24 ----- 10.200.200.3/24 ------ Routers/Firewalls only
       |                     |                      |
       V                     V                      V
10.10.10.1/24         10.20.20.1/24         10.30.30.1/24
```

Comment: I'm assuming `10.200.200.1/26` is a typo and should be `/24`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following on from my comment, something like this

```
      +----------+    +----------+   +----------+
      | Router 1 |    | Router 2 |   | Router 3 |
      +-------+--+    +----+-----+   +--+-------+
              |            |            |
              |            |            |10.200.200.0/24
              |            |            |
           +--v------------v------------v-+
           |           Router A           +-------------+
           +-+---------+---------------+--+             |
             |         |               |                |
             |         |               |                |
             |         |               |                |
+------------v-+ +-----v-------+ +-----v-------+ +------v------+
|192.168.1.0/24| |10.10.10.0/24| |10.20.20.0/24| |10.30.30.0/24|
+--------------+ +-------------+ +-------------+ +-------------+
```

Router 1 = 10.200.200.1

Router 2 = 10.200.200.2

Router 3 = 10.200.200.3

Router A = 10.200.200.254

This way, each of the networks at the bottom only has 1 router, and therefore 1 default route. The edge routers only need 1 internal route to access the internal subnets.

The internal router does become more complex because it needs to be aware of the multiple upstream routers, and keep track of connections to avoid the async routing. The benefits are worth it I believe: All the complexity is contained to that router, with the rest kept simple. And you can have full control over the multiple connections on that host. For example, you can NAT traffic from all 3 connections to the same internal server, but the server doesn't need to know any of that, the internal server will track each connection and route the traffic appropriately to avoid async.

This is very similar to the setup at my work, except we only have 2 upstream connections. Router A is a pair of Linux boxes running in H/A. Tracking of the connections is done using Policy Based Routing. The best guide I've found for PBR is: http://www.cyber.com.au/~twb/doc/dual-uplink.txt

Comment: Okay I see where you're going with this and it makes sense. I don't have multiple ISPs though; just one with a /28. I think your diagram would work except for the fact that each router has different functions. My `Router A` would be **pfSense** and I want to publish MS stuff behind **TMG2010** which would be `Router 1`. So in this diagram how would I publish `10.20.20.100` behind `Router 1` for users on `192.168.1.0` and external clients?

Comment: Why do you have 3 routers for the same /28? And what do you mean "Publish"?

Comment: I mean "publish" as used in MS TMG which means the client connects and authenticates to TMG instead of  directly to the Exchange or Sharepoint server. PfSense is my main router but can't perform the same type of authentication services at the application layer so I use ISA and TMG on the few other public IPs I have.

Comment: here's a link to Microsoft's definition of "publishing" a Sharepoint server http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc441501.aspx

Comment: Ohhhh, well I'm out then. I have no idea about that gear. Sorry.

Comment: Well it's basically only the routing part I wanted help with and so far at least you've helped confirm my idea makes some sense if not exactly how you'd do it. If no one else has any ideas in the next couple days I'll mark this as the answer. Thanks.

Comment: I marked this as the answer because although I'm not going to follow it totally this answer provides the principles I was looking for. Because I need to use TMG in front of some other servers I am going to go ahead with my proposed network diagram in the question. Thanks for the help and the info.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't offer any assistance with the MS side of this. Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

I would say you're introducing an extra level (literally) of complexity.

I'm assuming your async routing issues come from the situation eg `192.168.1.55` sends a packet to `10.20.20.55` but doesn't have a route for it via `192.168.1.2` so sends it via it's default at `192.168.1.1` where it gets redirected to `192.168.1.2`. The reply packet then goes directly from `192.168.1.2` to the original source, so `192.168.1.1` only see's the client to server packets, not the server to client packets.

In my environments, I avoid the firewall issue with async routing by adding a rule to allow bounce routing (anything in and out the same interface == same layer 2 == allow). You're not introducing any security issues since the src and dst of a packet are on the same layer 2 and can talk directly to each other anyway, you're just "encouraging" performance issues by routing sub-optimally.

Comment: Fukawi2, yes your description of the problem is correct in general although I simplified it a bit. I will attempt to explain the actual problem I've had which is not so much rules.

Comment: sorry didn't know "Enter" sent the comment.    Assume both `Router1` and `Router2` also have publicly addressable IPs on another interface and NAT is enabled. If `Server A` with IP `192.168.1.100` is published behind `Router2` but has `Router1` as it's def GW then a packet coming in from the internet via `Router2` will be replied to via `Router1` and the packet will be blocked by the firewall on the far end.  In this case I need to set Server A to use Router2 as the def GW and add static routes on Server A to networks behind the other routers and this seems too complex.

Comment: Ah I see. I think your original suggestion is reasonable then. Personally, I'd probably do it slightly differently, in that I'd isolate the 3 routers (to handle all the public in/out traffic) and then have another one to handle all the internal traffic. I'll post another answer with a better description.